# Setting margin-top of one element to the height of another element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a header at the top with a non-fixed height but a fixed position, and below that a content area. Now, I simply added a fixed padding-top to the element so the content would show below the header. I'm trying to do this using JavaScript and JQuery. I think the way I did it would be the best way, but it doesn't quite work.

[HTML]

```
<div class="contentPage" id="page_1" name="templates">
    <div class="contentPageHeader">
        <a href="#menu">
            <div class="pageBack">
                <h4>Back</h4>
            </div>
        </a>

        <h3>Templates</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="contentPageContent">
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS]

```
var headerHeight = $('.contentPageHeader').css( 'height' );
$('contentPageHeader').css('margin-top', headerHeight);
```

For a full demo visit this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdeujc0u/1/)

Comment: So you want 'templates' to stay as it is without going off the top of the page when someone scrolls down?

Comment: @JugglingBob Yes, that's why the contentPageHeader has a fixed position. Also, the contentPageContent has an `overflow-y` set to `scroll` so the div is scrollable instead of the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to fix your javascript:

```
    var headerHeight = $('.contentPageHeader').outerHeight();
    $('.contentPageContent').css('margin-top', headerHeight);
```

Also this code should be placed inside the `click` method.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdeujc0u/2/)

Comment: I didn't vote down (wondering why anyone would?). I find it nice that you got it to work, just wondering why you used `outerHeight()`, what's the difference with `css('height')`? Also, why does it need to be put inside the `click` method? I figured the document ready function would execute it properly as well.

Comment: `.contentPageHeader` has a padding, [outerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) method returns a height including padding and border. By default `.contentPageHeader` is hidden, and we can't get it's height properly, so we need to display it first on the page (click on link) and then calculate it's height.

Comment: I see, that totally makes sense. Thanks for making that clear. Accepting your answer because you were first ;)

Comment: Also, kind of off-topic. I want to center the h3 ("Templates") in the header, but the back button is taking up a bit of space to the h3 gets "centered" a bit to the right. How do I fix this?

Comment: Replace styles of `.pageBack` to this `.pageBack { position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 25px; }`.  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdeujc0u/6/)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the unit for marginTop for eg. `px or %`:

```
$('.contentPageHeader').css('margin-top', headerHeight + 'px');
//^^ missed a selector (the dot)
```

Comment: Fixed it in my JSFiddle, but still doesn't work (I added a red background color to it and it would still show through the header.) But thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {

        if (this.hash) {
            var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

            var $toElement = $("div[name=" + hash + "]");

            if (hash == "menu") {
                $('.contentPage').fadeOut(300);
                $($toElement).fadeIn(300);

            } else {
                $('#menu_holder').fadeOut(300);
                $($toElement).fadeIn(300);

            }
        }
       var headerHeight = $('.contentPageHeader').css( 'height' );  //your code added here
       $('.contentPageHeader').css('margin-top', headerHeight);  
    });


});
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/mdeujc0u/3/

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mdeujc0u/5/

Comment: No, this way you're setting the margin-top of the header to the height of the header. I want the margin-top of the content to be the height of the header.